# query user with powershell, output to email

Tags: powershell

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here in powershell. I am trying to email myself logged in user accounts on user change but I can't get it to work properly, it just gives me garbled unformatted messages. It works to a point but I would like it formatted instead of emailing me a single line.

Is this possible?

````
$users = query user /server:localhost
$SmtpServer = 'xx.xx.xx.xx' # SMTP Server name
$Port = 25                 # SMTP server port number – default is 25
$From = 'no-reply-server@xx.xx.xx.xx'  # from address - doesn't have to be valid, just in the format user@domain.ext and something your mail filter will not block
$To = 'xxxx@gmail.com'    # email address to send test to 
$Subject = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx - Server login detected of account.'    # email subject
$Body = 'This is an automated alert to notify you that there has been a change in user status:

'+$users+'

'     # email body

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $Port -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body ```

I get the email as follows: 

USERNAME SESSIONNAME ID STATE IDLE TIME LOGON TIME accountname rdp-tcp#39 3 Active . 3/30/2021 5:54 PM accountname2 rdp-tcp#94 9 Active 29 3/30/2021 9:01 PM
````

Comment: your `$Users` is just an array of strings. have you tried to parse it, build a `[PSCustomObject]` for each user, put that into a collection, and - finaly - use that collection? plus, there is a cmdlet named `ConvertTo-Html` ... [*grin*]

Comment: I got it thanks to your comment, thank you.

Comment: kool! glad to have helped ... and to see that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would post my solution as I got it to format the way I wanted. Thank you Lee_Dailey. I'm sure there is a shorter route but I am new to this.

```
function Get-TSSessions {
    param(
        $ComputerName = "localhost"
    )

    query user /server:$ComputerName |
    #Parse output
    ForEach-Object {
        # trim spaces at beginning and end
        $_ = $_.trim() 
        # insert , at specific places for ConvertFrom-CSV command
        $_ = $_.insert(22,",").insert(42,",").insert(47,",").insert(56,",").insert(68,",")
        # Remove every space two or more spaces
        $_ = $_ -replace "\s\s+",""
        # for debug purposes, comment out above row and uncomment row below
        #$_ = $_ -replace "\s","_"

        # output to pipe
        $_

    } |
    #Convert to objects
    ConvertFrom-Csv
}

$users = foreach ($user in GET-TSSessions)
{ 
    if ($user.'IDLE TIME' = ".") {
     $idletime = "Not Idle"
    } else {
     $idletime = $user.'IDLE TIME'
    }
    "<table width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Username:</b></td>
            <td><b>Sesstion Type:</b></td>
            <td><b>Session ID:</b></td>
            <td><b>Sesstion State:</b></td>
            <td><b>Idle Time:</b></td>
            <td><b>Logon Time:</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>"+$user.USERNAME+"</td>
            <td>"+$user.SESSIONNAME+"</td>
            <td>"+$user.ID+"</td>
            <td>"+$user.STATE+"</td>
            <td>"+$idletime+"</td>
            <td>"+$user.'LOGON TIME'+"</td>
        </tr>
    </table>"
}
$SmtpServer = '127.0.0.1' # SMTP Server name
$Port = 25                 # SMTP server port number – default is 25
$From = 'emailhere@email.com'  # from address - doesn't have to be valid, just in the format user@domain.ext and something your mail filter will not block
$To = 'emailhere@email.com'    # email address to send test to 
$Subject = 'Server login detected'        # email subject
$Body = 'This is an automated alert to notify you that there has been a change in user status:<br /><br />

'+$users+'

'     # email body
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $Port -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml $Body
```

Comment: neatly done! as you mentioned, there are other ways to do it ... but you got it done, and doing the job is what actually counts. [*grin*] ///// ps - you can accept your own Answer AND you can upvote it ...